# load multiple audio files to be played simultaneously even with poor internet connection

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

I have developed a functional multi-track audio player, and if i am connected to wifi, this player works as intended.  I need the files to play simultaneously.  But, if I am on my phone, it plays the first file, then the second, then third and so on.  Is there a way i can send all selected files to the server first, then send it back to the user to be listened to all together?  Please help.  Need to get this site launched as soon as possible.

```
  makeSong = function(f) {
var add, button, path, play;
path = curpath.concat(["" + f + ".mp3"]).join('/');
button = function(cls, onclick) {
  return $('<i/>').addClass(cls).addClass('link').addClass('fa').addClass("fa-" +    cls).click(onclick);
};
play = button('play', function() {
  play = $(this).hasClass('fa-play');
  if (play) {
    multiPlayer.stop();
    singlePlayer.play1(path);
  } else {
    singlePlayer.stop();
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-play', !play);
  return $(this).toggleClass('fa-pause', play);
});
add = button('plus', function() {
  return addItem(f, path);
});
return $('<div/>').addClass('sound     cf').text(f).append($('<div/>').addClass('buttons     left').append(play).append(add));
};

addSongs = function(fnames) {
var $songs, f, _i, _len, _results;
$songs = $('.sounds').empty();
_results = [];
for (_i = 0, _len = fnames.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  f = fnames[_i];
  _results.push(makeSong(f).appendTo($songs));
}
return _results;
};

currentPath = [];

loadSongs = function(path) {
return $.getJSON('/api/dir', {
  parts: JSON.stringify(path)
}, function(d) {
  curpath = path;
  return addSongs(d.fnames);
});
};

parentFolder = function(x) {
return x.parents('.folder').first();
};

getPath = function(elem) {
var parent;
parent = parentFolder(elem);
if (parent.length === 0) {
  return [];
}
return getPath(parent).concat([parent.attr('data-folder')]);
};

$('.categories .folder span.link').click(function() {
loadSongs(getPath($(this)));
$('.categories .folder').removeClass('active');
return parentFolder($(this)).addClass('active');
});

$('.player .play').click(function() {
var $i, play;
$i = $(this).find('i');
play = $i.hasClass('fa-play');
if (play) {
  multiPlayer.playAll();
} else {
  multiPlayer.stop();
}
$i.toggleClass('fa-play', !play);
return $i.toggleClass('fa-pause', play);
});

$('.player .sound').click(function() {
var $i, mute;
$i = $(this).find('i');
mute = $i.hasClass('fa-volume-up');
if (mute) {
  multiPlayer.mute();
} else {
  multiPlayer.unmute();
}
$i.toggleClass('fa-volume-up', !mute);
return $i.toggleClass('fa-volume-off', mute);
});

$('.button.buy').click(function() {
var x;
x = [];
$('.things .thing').each(function() {
  return x.push($(this).attr('data-path'));
});
if (x.length > 0) {
  return window.location.href = "/buy?" + ($.param({
    songs: JSON.stringify(x)
  }));
} else {
  return alert('Please add some songs below first.');
}
});

$('.folder .link').click(function() {
return $(this).closest('.folder').children('.subfolders').toggle();
});

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: Please post code here. We don't need all of it. I'm just looking for `<track>` tags or relevant JavaScript.

Comment: you can play() then pause() each <audio> tag, then play() them all at once , once canplay has fired the same # of times as the count of <audio> tags

Comment: I can post more code if this isn't the right code, i have all the files @PHPglue

Comment: @dandavis hey thank you for that! the only problem is, i don't know where to implement in the code... What would it take to get you to help me fix my multi player on my site to perform this function, but with a button in allLoaded like you suggested...  If you go to protunesaudio.com and go to hiphop/drums folder, add dreams drums, then hiphop/bass and hiphop?piano and add the "dreams" tracks as well, they are supposed to all start playing together, but they don't, especially if u have poor internet connection...  If you could help me i can pay.. i know u don't care about money but i need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple example of collecting and syncing four tracks. for a full app, you'll probably want to enable a button or something in *allLoaded()*, instead of just *play()*'n them all.

```
var tracks=[ // array of urls of mp3s
    "https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d1t05.mp3",
    "https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d2t02.mp3",
    "https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d2t03.mp3",
    "https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d1t10.mp3"
],

loadedCount=0, //how many tags are ready to play through?

tags=[]; // collection of <audio> tags


function allLoaded(){ //all tags can play, do something about it:
    tags.forEach(Function.call.bind(tags[0].play));
}

tracks.forEach(function(a){
    var aud=new Audio();
    tags.push(aud);    // add this track to collection
    aud.preload=true;  // important
    aud.controls=true; // only so we can see the player's time display to verify it works
    aud.oncanplaythrough=function(e){
        loadedCount++; //one more tags came in
        if(loadedCount===tracks.length) allLoaded(); //done loading
    };
    document.body.appendChild(aud); // needed to see time
    aud.src=a;  // load the mp3 url
    console.log("loading audio tag: ", aud);
});
```

obligatory fiddle demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/138vd2oc/

in term of paying, i don't care about money so please donate any extra money you have to a worthy cause, or at least give a random beggar $20 for me.

Comment: hey thanks so much. The only problem is I'm not that experienced and don't know where to implement the code. I have all the files of code for my site. If you could help me implement this into my site ProTunesaudio.com I will be in your debt. I have 200 for you if you could help me. I know you said you don't care about the money but it's what I have to offer bc this is my only shot at fixing this. Please let me know. Jasonwday121@gmail.com